# How do I fully intercept AND requeue http requests using dojo

Tags: angularjs, dojo, interceptor

I am down to a choice between angularjs and dojo as my front end MV* framework.  One particular functionality which in my mind is critical is the ability to do unobtrusive and transparent authentication.  I was extremely impressed with angular's capability in this regard using http interceptors.  See http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application for a good sample implementation/explanation.

It allows one to queue up any and all 401 responses while waiting for successful login and then re-transmit them once login is successful by using a combination of broadcast events, event handling, and http interceptor (plus a request queue).  The overhead on each request appears to be minimal.

I wanted to compare the ability of dojo to do the same, but from my examination it does not appear to be possible.  Examining the dojo documentation, it appears that this would probably have been possible in dojo 1.4 using the ioPipline, but that that is deprecated in favor of dojo/request/notify which does not appear to provide as low-level of an interception (specifically it doesn't appear to give access to the request object when an error is received). it is also not clear if it is possible to modify or replace the response from within the notified function...

Can anyone point me to a clear example of this having been accomplished using dojo's request/notify service or an alternate methodology using dojo?  Critical requirements are that the authentication be transparent to the protected functions/controllers/objects (they should simply receive a promise which is eventually fulfilled), that the authentication code be able to be centralized (it should not require modification to every object/event/etc that makes a request), and that it should be secure (in the sense that both authentication/authorization should happen on the server side and no javascript manipulation should be able to bypass that requirement)...

Answer (score 1):

You can register handlers within [dojo/request/registry](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/request/registry.html) to intercept and handle requests made using `dojo/request` any way you want. Here’s a modified (untested, probably slightly defective) example based on the reference guide:

```js
require([ "dojo/request/registry", "dojo/request/xhr" ], function (request, xhr) {
  request.register(function (url, options) {
    return xhr(url, options).response.then(function (response) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        // retry later
      }
      
      return response;
    });
  }, true);
});
```

With the above example, any request made with `dojo/request` will be intercepted and the method provided will be called. If you wanted to conditionally only match certain requests with this handler, you can pass another tester function as the first argument. This is detailed in the reference guide linked above.

All your handler function then needs to do is return a promise that will eventually resolve to the expected data.

Comment: This example does not work. The registered function is never called for an XHR request.