# Intercept dojo xhr call

Tags: dojo, xmlhttprequest, intercept

In relation to this question, [How do I fully intercept AND requeue http requests using dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433010/how-do-i-fully-intercept-and-requeue-http-requests-using-dojo)

I am interested in something similar, would dojo/aspect better suit?

Looking at the documentation here, http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/aspect.html The example given shows how to intercept dojo.xhr, but dojo.xhr is deprecated since 1.8??. and replaced by dojo/request. For the new API, dojo/request/notify is recommended by dojo documentation.

I am confused which one to use or should I use both methods? So I can cover all cases where some legacy codes are still using the old dojo.xhr API.

The other complication I can think of for using both methods, may be both methods are called for the same xhr request, thus duplicating the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dojo.xhr` is deprecated in favor of `dojo/request/xhr`, the [documentation for which you can find here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/xhr.html#dojo-request-xhr).

You can still use `dojo/aspect` as in the example. I've [created a fiddle that does just that](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/BYWfY/). The relevant code follows.

```
require([
    'dojo/request/xhr',
    'dojo/aspect'
], function(xhr, aspect) {
    aspect.before(xhr, 'post', function() {
        console.log('before POST');
    });

    // use xhr.post here...
});
```

If you still want to cover legacy code that uses `dojo.xhr`, you can extract the function you use in `aspect` and pass it to both objects:

```
function beforeXhr() {
    // ...
}

aspect.before(dojo, 'xhr', beforeXhr);
aspect.before(xhr, 'post', beforeXhr);
```

I haven't figured out how to use `dojo/aspect` on functions that are returned to the `require` callback, which means you'd have to repeat the `aspect` calls for 'GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE', etc. If anyone knows how to use `aspect` with a function object as in this example, I'd love to know.

Comment: Looking at the source code, dojo/request/xhr and dojo/request/utils, 'GET', 'PUT' and 'Delete'  I believe is just a alias for xhr, in the other word, it would call xhr under the hood. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, but if you use, e.g., `xhr.put`, you'd have to add another `aspect(xhr, 'put', ...)` call. Like I said in my answer, I'm not exactly sure how to use `aspect` with function objects like `xhr` as it comes through the `require` callback, so that's why that would be necessary.